# How to set up HP pen

Tags: touchscreen

I have an HP Envy touchscreen laptop and an HP pen. When using Ubuntu, the touchscreen only works if I use my finger, not the pen. How do I set up the pen? On Windows, it worked out of the box.

Comment: Did you get a solution?

Comment: The pen works for me, with some limitations.  The main one so far is that I can't find any way to change the scaling, so if I have multiple monitors connected then the pen motion is scaled so that the bottom of the laptop screen is the bottom of the whole virtual desktop and the top of the laptop screen is the top of the whole virtual desktop and so on.  It's not recognised as a wacom tablet so can't be set through the tablet settings in Gnome settings app.